# In shell scripting how can I take user input for a variable and match and validate the values?

Tags: bash, scripts

Arr=(exv err tmp)
Arr_1=(7 5 5)

In this I want to take input from the user so that it can validate arr and arr_1 value from the array. And if it no matches with the user input it throw an error.
I came up with

```
#!/bin/bash
Select a in arr[@]; do
If [[ "arr[@]" == *"a"* ]]; then
echo ""
break
else 
echo ""
fi
Done
```

Is there any other method from which I can achieve same result?

Comment: Just curious, if you want take input, shouldn't you be using `read` instead of `select` ?

Comment: I already have input defined. I just want to match the one I entered in terminal with the defined one.

Comment: It's hard to guess what "same result" means, since you haven't actually provided anything workable

Comment: @FoxChasin "Entered in terminal", I mean you take user input right ? The way I understand, you want to: 1. User to type to terminal 2. Return success if found in array 3. Return error if not found in array. Am I right ?

Comment: @Liso yes you got right.

Comment: I am using select for doing this . Is there any other way?